# Can´t get response in angular from asp.net core web api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I hope somebody can help. I´ve created a new asp.net core angular project in visual studio and a simple api method just like this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Users")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> CheckAPIConnection()
    {
        return Json(new { success = true }); 
    }
```

then I´ve created a new service in angular

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 

@Injectable() 
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: Http) {

}

checkAPIConnection() {
    let result = this.http.get("/api/Users/CheckAPIConnection");
    let jso:any;
    result.subscribe(res => jso = res);
    console.log(jso);
    if (jso.success == true) return true;
    else return false; 
}
```

In fiddler the request succeeds and the response is correct. But console.log tells me that "jso" is undefined. So I´ve tried to add

```
result.subscribe(res => jso = res.json());
```

but this does not change anything. I´ve also tried to enter "jso" with `jso["success"]` but I think the mayor problem is that jso is undefined.

I´ve tried to search for solutions but everbody used something like `then()` instead of `subscribe()`. Am i missing some imports or so? (Sorry I´m very new to angular especially in receiving data from api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to `console.log` inside the `subscription` as

```
result.subscribe(res => {
       jso = res.json();
       console.log(jso);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `do` operator of `rxjs` to check if the data is returned from service or not as below,

```
result.subscribe(res => jso = res)
      .do(response =>  console.log(response));
```

**Reason** :

- Http Request is `async` so log statement will be executed before the result is binded to variable.

Answer (score 0):

you should use 
result.subscribe(res => this.jso = res);

Comment: `jso` is a local variable, so `this.jso` is not valid.